# I face some position problems in css

Tags: css

lately I've started coding with some css and html and I decided to make my own first website, so I had some problems in changing the position of a div containing two buttons("s'inscrire" and "se connecter") ... Also when I hover on the header list, it starts moving upwards and downwards, I changed the padding, the margin... But nothing happens!

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway');
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Raleway; 
}
body{
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),
    url('1.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
}
.main ul{
 float: right;
 display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 position: sticky;

}
.main ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
}
.main ul li i{
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #eccc68; 
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.main ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 7px;

}
.main ul li a:hover{
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
 transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.main ul li.active a{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
}
.main ul ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: none;
}
.main ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
}
.login ul{
 float: right;
 position: fixed;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 12px;

}

.logo img{
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 0;
}
header{
 background-color: rgba(202, 211, 200,0.6);
}
.main{
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
}

.title img{
 width: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-100%);

}
.title p{
 width: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 54%;
 left: 50%;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: Montserrat;
 font-weight: lighter;
 transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
 text-align: center;
 color: #F8EFBA;
}
.button{
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
}
.button a i{
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #eccc68; 
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.btn{
 border: 1px solid #eccc68;
 border-radius: 15px;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
 transition: 0.6s ease;

}
.footer{
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 height: 60px;
}
.footer ul{
 transform: translateX(1800px);
 margin-right: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.footer ul li a i{
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #eccc68;
}

.footer ul li{
 display: inline-block;
}
.footer h5{
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #eccc68;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0.7;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Trip Buddy | Your free online travel guide</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="acceuil.html"><img src="2.png"></a>
   </div>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-city"></i>Villes dispo</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Marrakech</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rabat</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tanger</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Essaouira</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding"></i>Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">S'inscrire</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Se connecter</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  <div class="title">
   <img src="2.png">
   <p>Trip Buddy est ton premier accompagnant guide en ligne. Rejoignez notre nombreuse communauté et télecharger l'application sur toutes les platformes GRATUITEMENT!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
   <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>Regarder video</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>Aide</a>
  </div>
 </header>
 <footer>
  <div class="footer">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-snapchat-square"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
   <h5>
    &copy;Khalil 2019
   </h5>
  </div>
 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Please if you can fix this problem I'm gonna be so grateful for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you want to positioned those buttons? Please make this clear.

Comment: Hello,
I want them to be positionned at the top right corner of the web page... Because they are sign up and sign in buttons.
Also can you please clarify to me how to make elements positions relative to the page size ?

Comment: I add some code for the `login` area. `.login {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding:15px;
}
.login ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
}`
Please check codepen example for the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Changed the following CSS code and menu now fixed.

```
    .main ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 7px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    transition:all 0.6s ease; /* this will be always at normal stage not at hover*/

}
.main ul li a:hover{
    background-color: #fff; 
    color: #000;
}
```

Please have a look at this at [codepen](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/byGvwd)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Raleway');
*{
 margin:0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: Raleway; 
}
body{
 background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.4), rgba(0,0,0,0.4)),
    url('1.jpg');
 background-position: center;
 background-size: cover;
 height: 100vh;
}
.main ul{
 float: right;
 display: block;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top: 20px;
 position: sticky;

}
.main ul li{
 display: inline-block;
 width: 150px;
}
.main ul li i{
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #eccc68; 
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.main ul li a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
 border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
 display: block;
 transition:all 0.6s ease; /* this will be always at normal stage not at hover*/

}
.main ul li a:hover{
 background-color: #fff; 
 color: #000;
}
.main ul li.active a{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
}
.main ul ul li{
 list-style-type: none;
 display: none;
}
.main ul li:hover ul li{
 display: block;
}
.login ul{
 float: right;
 position: fixed;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 12px;

}

.logo img{
 float: left;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-left: 0;
}
header{
 background-color: rgba(202, 211, 200,0.6);
}
.main{
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: auto;
}

.title img{
 width: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-100%);

}
.title p{
 width: 40%;
 position: absolute;
 top: 54%;
 left: 50%;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: Montserrat;
 font-weight: lighter;
 transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
 text-align: center;
 color: #F8EFBA;
}
.button{
 position: absolute;
 top: 60%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-100%);
}
.button a i{
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #eccc68; 
 opacity: 0.6;
}
.btn{
 border: 1px solid #eccc68;
 border-radius: 15px;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:hover{
 background-color: #fff;
 color: #000;
 transition: 0.6s ease;

}
.footer{
 width: 100%;
 position: fixed;
 bottom: 0;
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
 height: 60px;
}
.footer ul{
 transform: translateX(1800px);
 margin-right: 0px;
 list-style-type: none;
 font-size: 15px;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.footer ul li a i{
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-right: 5px;
 color: #eccc68;
}

.footer ul li{
 display: inline-block;
}
.footer h5{
 font-size: 11px;
 color: #eccc68;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0.7;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Trip Buddy | Your free online travel guide</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="main">
   <div class="logo">
    <a href="acceuil.html"><img src="2.png"></a>
   </div>
   <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>Accueil</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-city"></i>Villes dispo</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Marrakech</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Rabat</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Tanger</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Essaouira</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-hand-holding"></i>Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i>Contact</a></li>
   </ul>
   
  </div>
  <div class="login">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">S'inscrire</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Se connecter</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  <div class="title">
   <img src="2.png">
   <p>Trip Buddy est ton premier accompagnant guide en ligne. Rejoignez notre nombreuse communauté et télecharger l'application sur toutes les platformes GRATUITEMENT!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="button">
   <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="far fa-play-circle"></i>Regarder video</a>
   <a href="#" class="btn"><i class="far fa-question-circle"></i>Aide</a>
  </div>
 </header>
 <footer>
  <div class="footer">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-twitter-square"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fab fa-snapchat-square"></i></a></li>
   </ul>
   <h5>
    &copy;Khalil 2019
   </h5>
  </div>
 </footer>

</body>
</html>
```